# How to say 温馨的家 in English, a warm family?

Tags: translation

温馨 （wen1xin1）：温暖。指亲切体贴的氛围

When I search **温馨的家** in Baidu, I got many photos of houses in warm color. If search **cozy home** in Google, I got similar photos of houses.
[image]

If I search **warm family**, Google shows me many family photos.
[image]

If I search **warm home**, the photos are about temperature
[image]

温馨 is a kind of atmosphere, it gives you a feeling of comfortable, kind, considerate…

The 温馨的家 in my understanding, it's a **mix** of warm family and cozy home.

So how to describe it in short? Better in 2 words, like "warm home". Or "warm family and cozy home" are the best way to describe it? Please share your thoughts with me :)

Comment: Yes, a warm and sweet family. Note, 馨 means fragrant or aromatic - a pleasant smelling,

Comment: This is all about _equivalence_ in translation. I personally quite like the rendition "a warm and loving home" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Mark Ma, family and house can't be the same thing in English, except perhaps for royal family bloodlines: The House of Tudor, The House of York (Plantagenet)

一座温暖又舒适的房子
a warm and a cozy home

一个温馨又有爱的家庭
a warm and loving family

Without a family, a home is just an empty house.

Comment: Very love the last sentence, it inspired me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it depends on the context.

Since 家 can either mean "home" or "family" and there seems to be no direct equivalent in English that encompasses these two concepts, how to put it in English depends on whether the 家 in the given sentence means "home" or "family". Here are some examples:

1. 她一进门就称赞道：”哇，你家好温馨啊！”
   (Upon entering, she complimented, "Wow! What a cozy home you have!")
2. 多么温馨的一家啊！
   (What a lovely family!)

Comment: I think the Chinese words in question are translation from a western language, most probably English, and you cannot find such a phrase in writings of the early 20th century. So "sweet home" might be the origin.